# Compare two maps with Firestore security rules (many-to-many security rule)?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

An admin can manage many forums and users can be members of many forums. If an admin is found to be a manager of a forum that a user is a member of, that admin should have permission to `read` that user's profile data. The security rule would have to be able to compare two maps to see if they have a common forumID, along the lines of:

```
// WARNING: INVALID CODE

"accounts": {
  ".read": "auth.token.permissions.fundIDsAdminMap.doAnyKeysMatch(resource.data.fundIDsMemberMap) === true"
}
```

Unfortunately comparing two maps requires special built-in function (as demonstrated in the example above), or loops, or recursion, none of which I believe exist in firebase rules at the moment.

What is the best way to model this?

One solution is to forego roles such as "fundAdmin" and instead directly record the `accountIDs` that can administer a specific object on the object itself. That way security can be performed against the logged in user's uid:

```
resource.data.administeredBy[request.auth.uid] == true

// doc would have administeredBy property
account.administeredBy= {
  accountID1: true,
  accountID5: true
};
```

The problem with this is that it pushes, and increases, lots of complexity to the `write` side of the equation. Every time an admin changes, many individual documents scattered all over have to be written to reflect the change. Also, a larger quantity of redundant data would have to be stored in many more disparate objects. Additionally the database will have to play a much larger role in permission management (due to having to store all these accountIDs) rather than having that mostly isolated to security rules. And finally it's simply strange not to be able to use a "roles" paradigm to organize permissions. Any clever solutions that don't have as many downsides?

Comment: Put all the admins into a known document's array field to check, or use Firebase Auth custom claims to grant access.

Comment: Hey,

Putting all the admins into a known document's array field leads to the same issues described at the bottom of the question I believe.

In fact I do use auth claims in the real environment. I have a map that gives an account admin access to various forums like this:

request.auth.permissions.fundAdmin[resource.data.fundID] == true. But it creates the same issue of having to compare maps.

Comment: Since we can't see the code you're using to access the document, we can't tell if you're doing it correctly. If you're suggesting that the user data is already in the document to modify, then you should illustrate the contents of that document, so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maps can be diffed in the firestore rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff

However, although your post title says Firestore, the example rules you gave look like RTDB rules, so please clarify which you're asking about.